# Java 8 Stream non static method stream cannot be referenced

Tags: java, java-stream

I have problem with streams in IDEA. 
I have a simple test:

```
 @Test
    public void shouldFlattenAListOfList() throws Exception {
        List<String> flatten = PTestImpl.flatten(
                asList("a", asList("b", asList("c", "d")), "e"));
        assertThat(flatten, hasSize(5));
        assertThat(flatten, hasItems("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));
    }
```

And static method

```
 public static <T> List<T> flatten(List<?> list){
        return list.stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());;
    }
```

But IDEA tells me:

```
Error:(44, 26) java: invalid method reference
  non-static method stream() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You're trying to call collection.stream() on every element of a List<?>. But a List<?>  doesn't contain instances of Collection. It contains Objects. You also seem to think that flatMap is recursive. It's not.

Comment: @Ravi - This isn't an exception, and the `static` in the OP's code has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @JBNizet ok so how should I replace List<?>?

Comment: That's not what you should replace. You should replace the content of the flatten() method by something else (that is recursive, and tests the type of the elements of the list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flatten` method body and its return type has to be changed, if you do not want to make any assumptions about the type of the elements in the received list:

```
public static List<?> flatten(List<?> list){
    return list.stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e instanceof List ? flatten((List) e).stream() : Stream.of(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```